# 2x2 row and column equations

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, grid-deduction

Rules: No paper or notes, but a calculator is accepted.

Post the exact time min wise of how long it took.

And obviously give the answer.

[image: 2 by 2 box of numbers arranged into equations, with sums/differences given. Top left plus top right equals 8. Bottom left minus bottom right equals 6. Top left plus bottom left equals 13. Top right plus bottom right equals 8.]

Comment: I'll admit, I would've taken forever without writing it down

Comment: This type of question is stupid because: i. One can, after seeing the question, get an instant idea of what do be done (it may take time to work out the idea, but generally one gets the main idea instantly), so it is stupid exercise, not a good problem. ii. It has some bad precontexts, the most horrible one that the time of solving this has a "corelation" with stupid "IQ".

Comment: @Arka Karmakar you're absolutely right. I think my inexperience with mathematics provided to the excessive time i spend on the problem.   I understand this now. I also used the word intelligence too loosely, i think the word i was looking for was processing speed. Because experiences with math aside, i do believe that some people will arise with a conclusion much faster than others. But this skill isnt Iq, or intelligence, or brain power, it's only a small sliver of those things. You'll have to excuse my ignorance as I'm a bit new to these sorts of things. But I'm thankful that I'm learning

Comment: I find it oddly amusing that you allow the use of a calculator for linear computations whose parameters are integers between 0 and 15 (21, if you consider the grand total).

Comment: The best part is that this puzzle already got 7 answers below:)

Comment: Haha i know 7 answers wow. I give that credit torwards my clickbait title lmao

Comment: You got lots of answers because you made it an intelligence contest.

Comment: @TylerJohnson: Yeah, it's great, and don't get sucked up in the delusional wormhole of "IQ". I was sucked up one time, and took a lot of disillusion realization to realize that the concept of "IQ" and comparing it is completely nonsense. Don't get sucked up, then you will do a lot of nonsense "IQ" tests followed by bunch of comparison-al nonsense.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar there's a lot of sense to IQ. I find that it correlates extremely well to a person's ability to take IQ tests.

Comment: Logic can sometimes work faster than math. The fact that 2 different sums add up to the same number and parity/CRC is 1 (due to the 13), it automatically means that we need non-int (.5 values). Hashing that in my mind from 0.5 in the initial box, got me the result in the 4th try. Total time ~ 1 min.

Comment: The OP seems to have completely misunderstood what IQ means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Took one minute to solve.

> This question has a reasonably easy solution if you can figure out the pattern in the the provided equations.
> Look at the first row equation and the second column equation.
> $a+b =8$
> $b+c =8$
> Notice that there is a common variable in the equations (the intersection of the equations in the picture denotes the common variable.) 
> Thus we can rewrite the set of equations as:
> $a+b=8$
> $c+b=8$
> Subtracting these two equations can make us realize that $a=c$. Which means the top left box is equal to bottom right box.

The problem can be rewritten as

> [image]

The values now seem fairly easy to compute.

> $a+c=13$
> $c-a=6$
> By adding the above equations, the variable $c$ can be resolved. By evaluation of $c$ and substituting into either of the above equations, variable $a$ can be calculated. After which variable $b$ can be calculated by substituting variable $a$ in $a+b=8$.

Comment: +1, this is how I solved it. Took me about 45 seconds to do in my head.

Comment: I failed to solve this because once I got `2c=13+6` I jumped to the conclusion that *Heck, there are no solutions by parity. What a trick question.*

Answer (score 9):

Let *a* be the top - left square, 
Let *b* be the top - right square, 
Let *c* be the bottom - left square, 
Let *d* be the bottom - right square,

> a = 3.5, 
>  b = 4.5, 
>  c = 9.5, 
>  d = 3.5

Method:

> Equations: 
>  a + b = 8 
>  c - d = 6 
>  Add to get: a + b + c - d = 14 
>  
>  a + c = 13 
>  b + d = 8 
>  Add to get: a + b + c + d = 21 
>  Subtract equations to get: 2d = 7 
>  d = 7/2 = 3.5 
>  c - 3.5 = 6 
>  c = 9.5 
>  a + 9.5 = 13 
>  a = 3.5 
>  3.5 + b = 8 
>  b = 4.5

Also ~ two minutes.

Comment: You used virtual paper or you might've done it in your mind first

Comment: Once I saw what to do it was easy. All you need is to get one number from the method, and everything collapses.

Comment: You had a great explanation regardless

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Two mins? All men are created equal my ass LMAO. Smooth answer btw

Comment: @TylerJohnson I don't think it's fair to judge someone's intelligence on how fast they solve math problems

Comment: @Areeb yeah your right,intelligence is too broad to single out one skill. But it has something to with something

Comment: Literally me one time: [Solving a puzzle] Dad: Ok, so, 32 + 32 is 50, and now we just add the other 50, and we get 100! Me: Yeah! Let's test this out! (Bub): Uh... guys?

Answer (score 2):

> 3.5  + 4.5 = 8
>  9.5 - 3.5 = 6

This took me two minutes to solve.  There are four variables and four equations.  Basic algebra rules the day.

Comment: 3.5 + 3.5 != 8 so it doesn't work

Comment: Transcription error.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Eyyy it works now and just before all the other answers!

Comment: That's absolutely insane. What's your estimated iq? i would definitely love to know.

Comment: @TylerJohnson I'm a university dropout.  Had a 3.8 / 4.0 in high school.

Comment: I did it in my head using three equations noting the two opposite corners would have the same value. It was very easy to get the 9.5 that way.

Comment: @TylerJohnson I guess the difficulty is in assuming that the variables are integers simply because the answers are integers.  It's easy to run the 1/7 2/6 3/5 4/4 pairs in your head and then get stumped.  Skipping the assumption and solving skips that heartache.

Comment: @LeppyR64 I'll take your advice. You also summed up my situation perfectly. I was assuming there was a rule that made the answer only exclusive To natural numbers for the first 13 mins.

Answer (score 2):

> Let squares be $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. We have $a$ $+$ $b$ $+$ $c$ $+$ $d$ $=$ $21$, $a$ $+$ $b$ $+$ $c$ $-$ $d$ $=$ $14$, so $2d$ $=$ $7$, $d$ $=$ $3.5$. Got this bit in 5 seconds. Full square:
>
> ```
> 3.5 + 4.5 = 8
>  +     +
> 9.5 - 3.5 = 6
>  =     =
>  13    8
> ```
>
> $20$ seconds in total - roughly

Comment: 20 f@×king seconds. Ok i have to know the number to your iq

Comment: it's more of a concept :)

Comment: So your saying you solving that problem had nothing to do with intelligence, but more with the way you solved it?

Comment: it's a standard method - the sum of the sum of the rows = the sum of the sum of the columns in a usual array - in this case there is a minus, so we can apply simultaneous equations

Comment: Experience with these types of puzzles (and perhaps just puzzles/math in general) definitely would help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to solve in your mind (I did it in this way in 2-3 minutes to solve and confirm):

> if you sum all equations you will be summing up the squares two times but the square with opposite signs (the forth square) cancels and you left with summing up squares with + signs two times. So 2x(first+second+third squares) = 8 + 8 + 6 + 13 = 35, hence first+second+third = 17.5, you know first + second = 8 therefore third = 9.5. Then it follows.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as everybody else, with a *slightly* different twist:

> Add the columns:
> \begin{align}a + c = 13\\+\qquad b + d = ~~8\\\hline\llap{\text{Add to get:}\quad}a + b + c + d = 21\\\llap{\text{Subtract:}\qquad}-\qquad a+b=~~8\\\hline\llap{\text{to get:}~~\qquad\qquad\qquad}c+d=13\end{align}
> So we have $c+d=13$ and $c-d=6$, so $c$ must be the average of $13$ and $6$. 
> We can calculate this as
> \begin{align}c+d&=13\\+\qquad c-d&=~~6\\\hline\llap{\text{Add to get:}\quad\qquad}2c~\phantom{+d}&=19\\[2ex]\llap{\text{So,}\quad\qquad\qquad}c~\phantom{+d}&=19\rlap{/2}\\[2ex]\llap{\implies\qquad\qquad}c&=~9\rlap{.5}\end{align}
> but I didn't need to do that. 
> I saved a few seconds by realizing
> that, since $c$ is equally distant from $13$ and $6$,
> it must be halfway between $13$ and $6$, i.e., their average.

Then (the same as everybody else),
it's a simple matter to solve for the other three:

> $c+d=13\implies 9.5+d=13\implies\boxed{d}=13-9.5=\boxed{3.5}$
> $a+c=13\implies a+9.5=13\implies\boxed{a}=13-9.5=\boxed{3.5}$
> $b+d=~8~\implies\,b+3.5=~8~\implies\boxed{b}=~~8-3.5=\boxed{4.5}$
> Interestingly,
> I didn't notice that $a=d$ until after I had solved for their values.
>
> Results: $\qquad a=3.5\qquad b=4.5\qquad c=9.5\qquad d=3.5$
>
> So the filled-in grid is:
> $$\begin{array}{c}\Large{3.5}&+&\Large{4.5}&=&\Large{8}\\+& &+\\\Large{9.5}&-&\Large{3.5}&=&\Large{6}\\||& &||\\\Large{13}&&\Large{8}\end{array}\hskip1.1in$$

I didn't exactly time myself,
but I'm pretty sure that I did this in under a minute. 
In deference to [rand al'thor](/questions/41938/how-fast-can-you-solve-this#comment124567_41959),
I'll stipulate that I took at least 45 seconds.

<sup>P.S. For convenience, I copied some of the equations
from [greenturtle3141's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41941/19765).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This took me a minute using brute force.

> I instinctively started with the bottom row first because it seemed to have a narrower range of reasonable answers. After plugging 8,9,10 in the bottom left corner it was pretty obvious that a whole number wasn't going to work - my answers for the top row were bracketing 8. Once I reached that conclusion the problem was basically solved.

I can see from other answers that there is a more theoretical way to solve the problem but I figured it would take me longer to work out the theory than to solve it with brute force.